# Apache Ignite cache long running transaction

Tags: ignite

Sometimes, not always, when the topology of my cluster changes it happens that my application hangs for up to 1 minute or more. In the log I then see the below Ignite warning. I guess this is the reason why my application hangs at a cache operation.

What is causing the long transaction? I expect it is either network issues or GC?

I wasn't able to find out which cache operation in my code is causing this long transaction. Does the warning help me find out what operation it is?

```
22:00:30.456 [grid-timeout-worker-#63][101] WARN  org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic-[warning] Found long running transaction [startTime=21:58:57.176, curTime=22:00:30.456, tx=GridNearTxLocal [mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], nearLocallyMapped=false, colocatedLocallyMapped=false, needCheckBackup=null, hasRemoteLocks=false, trackTimeout=false, lb=null, thread=<failed to find active thread 1498>, mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], super=GridDhtTxLocalAdapter [nearOnOriginatingNode=false, nearNodes=[], dhtNodes=[], explicitLock=false, super=IgniteTxLocalAdapter [completedBase=null, sndTransformedVals=false, depEnabled=false, txState=IgniteTxStateImpl [activeCacheIds=[], recovery=null, txMap=[]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=147994093, order=1536523104974, nodeOrder=74], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=1498, startTime=1536523137176, nodeId=e8153238-1d5a-4149-8db8-83a9fc820750, startVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=147994093, order=1536523104974, nodeOrder=74], endVer=null, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], duration=93280ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=0]]]]
```

My caches are created like this:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="MFDB_JobList" />
    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
    <property name="backups" value="0" />
    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/> 
    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
    <property name="indexedTypes">
        <list>
            <value>java.util.UUID</value>
            <value>CacheJobQueueEntry</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The relevant ignite configuration looks like this:

```
<property name="networkTimeout" value="60000" />
<property name="networkSendRetryCount" value="10" />
<property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="100000" />
<property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="100000" />
```

Comment: It sounds like exchange goes way too slow in your cluster. Could you please share logs and few consecutive thread dumps taken while application hangs?

Comment: @DonTequila  How many nodes in the cluster do you have? How much data are you storing? Is persistence to disk enabled?

Comment: @Dmitiy sorry for missing all this information. These errors already came with only 3 nodes. Persitance is emabled. I think I found out that I was querying a cache with lots of data using SqlQuery, this took quite long time on every cache update. Now I'm using SqlFieldsQuery with only a few columns and the whole cluster is must faster. Data thoughput was about average 500mb/s before, now only 40kb/s. I will keep an eye on it if the error still happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

go through below link:-

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6980

And also try

```
<property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
```

with Async Cache operation. It might help to minimize above issue.